# How to create ///summary

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I generate these kind of summaries in Visual Studio?

```
/// <summary>
///  Returns a number
/// </summary>
/// <param name="num"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This adds noise to your code; at best it is annoying duplication but usually since nobody reads these things, they become out of date.

Comment: I found it useful to have these summary sections for methods in large codebase.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Type in `///` before your method, property, etc.  VS will generate the comment blocks automatically.

Comment: Pedantism: Visual Studio will automatically generate these comment blocks. This feature has nothing to do with the C# language itself.

Comment: Thats why it is a newbie question

Comment: @user It's still a good question.  Otherwise, at least with me, you just learn it by accident.

Comment: What's the equivalent for creating comment blocks automatically for a powershell script function in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 30):

As others have said, Visual Studio will, by default, add the documentation template automatically when you type three slashes in a row above the member declaration. If the member has any Attributes applied to it, then type the slashes on the line above the attributes.

Note, however, that one of the most useful things to document for a method (or constructer, property, etc.) is the exceptions that the method may generate. Those can be added by typing `///<exception` after the rest of the documentation. When you accept the Intellisense suggestion, you will be provided with a place for the Exception type as an XML attribute, and you can fill in the circumstances in the exception element content.

If any parameters are added to a method after the documentation is already produced, then the Intellisense will also be very helpful in filling in the new paramter name when you go to add it to the documentation. It is a pretty slick feature.

Answer (score 8):

type three times / and Visual Studio will fill rest of the code.

Answer (score 8):

Put the cursor on the line just before the method or class that you want to document and type `///`. Visual Studio will generate the XML doc tags, like `<summary>` and `<param>`, then you can fill in the details.

Answer (score 7):

Use tools like [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). It will generate using right clicking a method name.

Comment: No answer to the question, a recommendation for a tool. Should be a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Like George says, /// on the line just above will autogenerate it.

Beyond the boilerplate comment template it gives you, I'd recommend taking a look at the other tags you may use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx

This may be used in combination with other tools such as Sandcastle to automatically build CHM guides, etc.

Answer (score 5):

For Controllers: Use 3 forward slash before Methods i.e. /// which will generate summary tag like this,

```
     /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="searchKey"></param>
     /// <returns></returns>
```

For Models: Use 3 forward slash before an auto-property i.e. /// which will generate summary tag like this,

```
     /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
```

Answer (score 4):

On the line before your property/method/etc, simply type /// and then Visual Studio will automatically add the XML tags.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to make this even easier.

Comment: No answer to the question, a recommendation for a tool. Should be a comment.