# Inline Standard Xml Documention in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coding-style, xml-documentation

When its expanded...

[image]

When its collapsed...

[image]

When i tried with same approach it did not work..

[image]

Please guide me how to write this kind of standard commenting as used in Microsoft Apis.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ///summary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522889/how-to-create-summary)

Comment: @Mate No, Its another popular XML documentation which consumes 1 line while collapsed.

Answer (score -1):

It is done automatically by the visual studio editor. If not then check the Tools->Options->TextEditor->C#->Advanced->Editor help and check second checkbox